# Python model targeting n variable prediction equation

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression

I am looking to build a predictive model and am working with our current JMP model. Our current approach is to guess an nth degree polynomial and then look at which terms are not significant model effects. Polynomials are not always the best and this leads to a lot of confusion and bad models. Our data can have between 2 and 7 effects and always has one response.

I want to use python for this, but package documentation or online guides for something like this are hard to find. I know how to fit a specific nth degree polynomial or do a linear regression in python, but not how to 'guess' the best function type for the data set.

Am I missing something obvious or should I be writing something that probes through a variety of function types? Precision is the most important. I am working with a small (~2000x100) data set.

Potentially I can do regression on smaller training sets, test them against the validation set, then rank the models and choose the best. Is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using other regression models instead of the vanilla Linear Model.

You can use something like this for polynomial regression:

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(input_data)
```

And you can constraint the weights through the Lasso Regression

```
clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha = 0.5, positive = True)
clf.fit(X_,Y_)
```

where Y_ is the output you want to train against.

Setting alpha to 0 turns it into a simple linear regression. alpha is basically the penalty imposed for smaller weights. You can also make the weights strictly positive. Check this out [here.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html)

Run it with a small degree and perform a cross-validation to check how good it fits.

Increasing the degree of the polynomial generally leads to over-fitting. So if you are forced to use degree 4 or 5, that means you should look for other models.

You should also take a look at this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004374/how-to-calculate-the-likelihood-of-curve-fitting-in-scipy) This explains how you can curve fit.

Answer (score 0):

[ANOVA (analysis of variance)](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/anova.html) uses covariance to determine which effects are statistically significant... you shouldn't have to choose terms at random.

However, if you are saying that your data is inhomogenous (i.e., you shouldn't fit a single model to all the data), then you might consider using the [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) toolkit to build a classifier that could choose a subset of the data to fit.